# MySQL-Copy value from one column to another in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `a1` like this

```
number    |   name
1             John
2             Jake
3             Linda
```

And another table `a2` with exact same format as `a1` (2 columns `number` and `name`) but has no values at all. How can I copy values from `a1.number`to `a2.number` ?

I tried

```
UPDATE a2, a1 SET a2.number = a1.number
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your second table has no data, then you want to use `insert`:

```
insert into t2(number, name)
    select number, name
    from t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your second table already have rows and you want to update the `num` column
Try this:

```
update a2
inner join a1 on a1.id = a2.id
set a2.num = a1.num
```

Else you should go with Gordon Linoff's answer

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use

```
insert into a2 
    select a1.number 
    from a1;
```

if you really just want to copy column number of a1 to a2, then

```
update a1 
join a2 on a1.number = a2.number 
set a2.name = '';
```